# Get Total sales value for multiplying two columns then SUM

Tags: php, postgresql

I am trying to get a SUM of 2 Columns multiplied together in PHP and Postgresql. I seem to get an empty result.

quantity and accessory_price is in one table named accessory_only_solds

Here is the NON working code:

```
$aval = "SELECT TO_CHAR(SUM(CAST(accessory_price AS NUMERIC * quantity)),'999,999.99') AS atotal FROM accessory_only_solds";
$avalue = pg_query($aval);
$arev = pg_fetch_assoc($avalue);
echo $arev['atotal'];
```

if i remove quantity i get the SUM of accessory_price which is not correct to get the overall total because some accessories are more than 1 quantity

Working for SUM of accessory_price but without multiplying to quantity:

```
    $aval = "SELECT TO_CHAR(SUM(CAST(accessory_price AS NUMERIC)),'999,999.99') AS atotal FROM accessory_only_solds";
    $avalue = pg_query($aval);
    $arev = pg_fetch_assoc($avalue);
    echo $arev['atotal'];
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

[image: table]

Comment: Shouldn't that be `as NUMERIC) * quantity`? (Note the parenthesis.)

Comment: yeah you are right worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like your cast has a multiplication problem within it, which is causing problems.

Try this:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(SUM(CAST(accessory_price AS NUMERIC )* quantity),'999,999.99') AS atotal FROM accessory_only_solds
```